# Load model class to Kotlin class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a java implementation of Model class being loaded into a Java class. I converted the class to Kotlin but now am getting unsolved reference load

I've tried URlclassloader but that creates even more errors

The Java implementation in recyclerview onBindViewHolder

```
    holder.decreaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(AppDatastore.getPosData().get(position).getProductItemQuantity().equals("1")){

                        }else {

                            int count = 1;
                            count = Integer.parseInt(AppDatastore.getPosData().get(position).getProductItemQuantity());
                            long id = AppDatastore.getPosData().get(position).getId();
                            int sum = count - 1;
                            PosData posData = PosData.load(PosData.class, id);
                            posData.setProductItemQuantity(sum + "");
                            posData.save();
                        }

                        holder.integerNumber.setText(AppDatastore.getPosData().get(position).getProductItemQuantity());
                        ipassPos.passPos();

                    }
                });
```

The Kotlin class

```
 holder.decreaseButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (AppDatastore.posData[position].productItemQuantity == "1") {

            } else {

                var count = 1
                count = Integer.parseInt(AppDatastore.posData[position].productItemQuantity)
                val id = AppDatastore.posData[position].id!!
                val sum = count - 1

          //error occurs here showing unresolved reference load

                val posData = PosData.load<PosData>(PosData::class.java, id)
                posData.productItemQuantity = sum.toString() + ""
                posData.save()
            }

            holder.integerNumber.setText(AppDatastore.posData[position].productItemQuantity)
            ipassPos.passPos()
        }
```

The PosData class is

```
@Table(name = "PosData")
class PosData : Model {


    @Column(name = "productItemId")
    var productItemId: String? = null
    @Column(name = "productItemName")
    var productItemName: String? = null
    @Column(name = "productItemQuantity")
    var productItemQuantity: String? = null
    @Column(name = "productItemKind")
    var productItemKind: String? = null
    @Column(name = "productItemUnitPrice")
    var productItemUnitPrice: String? = null
    @Column(name = "productItemImage")
    var productItemImage: String? = null

    constructor() : super() {}

    constructor(productItemId: String, productItemName: String, productItemQuantity: String, productItemKind: String, productItemUnitPrice: String, productItemImage: String) {
        this.productItemId = productItemId
        this.productItemName = productItemName
        this.productItemQuantity = productItemQuantity
        this.productItemKind = productItemKind
        this.productItemUnitPrice = productItemUnitPrice
        this.productItemImage = productItemImage
    }

    fun setPosData(productItemId: String, productItemName: String, productItemQuantity: String, productItemKind: String, productItemUnitPrice: String, productItemImage: String) {
        this.productItemId = productItemId
        this.productItemName = productItemName
        this.productItemQuantity = productItemQuantity
        this.productItemKind = productItemKind
        this.productItemUnitPrice = productItemUnitPrice
        this.productItemImage = productItemImage
    }

    fun posDataList(): List<PosData> {
        return getMany(PosData::class.java, "PosData")
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to do that in Kotlin or even a better way would be of great help

Comment: can you show your `PosData` class?

Comment: Sure, updated with PosData class

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm using below class model:-

```
class AddAlertOverViewItem {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("email")
    lateinit var email: String
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("alert_type")
    lateinit var alertType: String
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("alert_name")
    lateinit var alertName: String
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("sms")
    lateinit var sms: String
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("alert_id")
    lateinit var alertId: String
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("notification")
    lateinit var notification: String
}
```

In your adapter class. access like this.

```
addAlertOverViewItem.sms
addAlertOverViewItem.alertType
addAlertOverViewItem.notification
addAlertOverViewItem.alertName
```

Here `addAlertOverViewItem` is the object of your model class and `sms, alertType, etc.` your model key to access value of that key.